# Don't have full block data on my full node

Tags: raw-data

I am revising my blockchain parser and I'm encountering an issue where I only have block headers but not the corresponding block data on my machine for blocks past a certain height (on my machine it started at block #594606 and from there on I only had data for some blocks.)  There is a bit flag 'BLOCK_HAVE_DATA' which, if not set, indicates that we have the header in the leveldb database but not the corresponding block data on disk in the .dat files.

Unfortunately I need that data for my parser to work, so I don't know (a) why it is missing and (b) how to get the data on my hard drive.

Is there some command line option I can pass when I launch the bitcoin core node software for make sure I have data for all blocks on my hard drive?

Thanks,

John W. Ratcliff

** Note: I asked this question of ChatGPT and it provided the following response. I don't know if it is correct or not, but I'm going to try it.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, when you say "past", do you mean blocks older than 594606 or blocks newer than 594606?

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I just realized that you say “past a certain height”. If you meant, that you don’t have the blocks below that height, my answer below applies. Otherwise, you might not have downloaded the remaining blocks yet?

---

It sounds like you are running your node in “pruning” mode. This is the default behavior when you are using `bitcoin-qt`, the GUI-mode. If you want to keep a complete copy of the blockchain you can either uncheck the option in the settings or add `prune=0` in the configuration (`bitcoin.conf`). Either way, you will need to indeed `reindex` after changing the setting to reacquire the missing blockdata.